# How to call initstate() method of another class from parent floating action button?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a tab with 2 tabs and a floating action button. 
I have a separate class for filling my tab bar view.
I want to make changes or call a method in that tabbarview from parent floating action button pressed method.
Below I have simplified the scenario with simple text and behaviour.
By swiping the tabs, the second initstate() method is called and debugger stops at

```
strTitle=widget.txt;
```

I need the same to happen on pressing the button.
If flutter can call initstate automatically while swiping why cant i do the same. There should be some way which I am unaware of.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyTabbedPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyTabbedPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _MyTabbedPageState createState() => _MyTabbedPageState();
}

class _MyTabbedPageState extends State<MyTabbedPage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  int i = 0;
  final List<Tab> myTabs = <Tab>[
    Tab(
      text: 'LEFT',
    ),
    Tab(text: 'RIGHT'),
  ];

  TabController _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(vsync: this, length: myTabs.length);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _tabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  pressed() {
    i = i + 1;
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        bottom: TabBar(
          controller: _tabController,
          tabs: myTabs,
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: pressed,
        child: Icon(Icons.power_settings_new),
      ),
      body: TabBarView(
        controller: _tabController,
        children: myTabs.map((Tab tab) {
          String label = tab.text.toLowerCase();
          if (label.contains("right")) {
            label = "Modified Right";
          }
          return Tabbarview1(label + ' ' + i.toString());
        }).toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Tabbarview1 extends StatefulWidget {
  final String txt;
  Tabbarview1(this.txt);
  @override
  _Tabbarview1State createState() => _Tabbarview1State();
}

class _Tabbarview1State extends State<Tabbarview1> {
  String strTitle = "0";
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    strTitle = widget.txt;
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Center(
        child: Text(strTitle),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the widget updates, you need to update its state as well:

```dart
class _Tabbarview1State extends State<Tabbarview1> {
  ...

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(Tabbarview1 oldWidget) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);

    if (oldWidget.txt != widget.txt) {
      setState(() {
        strTitle = widget.txt;
      });
    }
  }
```

Swiping back-and-forth works, because widget is disposed and inited once again with a new value.

Comment: This works, but on every activity. I want the code to execute only when i press the button and not on swipe or keyboard open/close activity.

Comment: @Faiz You can check that `txt` field changed like this: `if (oldWidget.txt != widget.txt) ...` and only then call setState